# Query to get rows by multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, having-clause

I have table for example like this:

| id_product | id_feature_value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 60 |
| 2 | 60 |
| 1 | 40 |
| 2 | 10 |

I want get distinct id_products where   id_feature_value = 60 and id_feature_value = 40
Its just example because I will need filter by more feature_values.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT  id_products WHERE id_feature_value=60 AND id_feature_value=40`.  But this will result in no output, because you should have said `or` and not `and`.  

Comment: How many `feature_value`values are you talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want products that have both features, you can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select id_product
from mytable
where id_feature_value in (40, 60)
group by id_product
having count(*) = 2
```

This assumes no duplicates. Otherwise, you need `count(distinct id_feature_value) = 2`.

You can easily extend that to handle more features per product: you just need to expand the `in` clause, and modify the literal number in the `having` clause accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

either using distinct and in :

```
select distinct id_products
from tablename
where id_feature_value IN ( 40, 60 , ...)
```

or group by

```
select id_products
from tablename
where id_feature_value IN ( 40, 60 , ...)
group by id_products
```